# Dismiss presenting view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following situation:

view controller A -> presents modally -> view controller B

view controller B -> presents modally -> view controller C

I would like to dismiss view controller "C" and go directly to "A" instead of showing "B" since it do not make sense to show "B" at that time.

How can I accomplish that ?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Look up "unwind segues"

Comment: Thanks! Could you set this as an answer so I can accept ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use segues to present view controllers from other view controllers.

To go backwards through a hierarchies you normally dismiss presented view controllers or you go back to specific view controllers through **unwind segues**.

Comment: interface builder only though.

Answer (score 10):

In 'view controller C' ->

Before iOS 6:
Use

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Or,

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

From and Above iOS 6:
Use

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Works great!!! I was only going up one level, but it seems you have to call the dismiss on the parent controller of the view you want to dismiss

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
[vcB dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]   //no Animation, so happens instantly
[vcA dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]  //with Animation, this is all you see
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be use navigation controllers if your B and C are related and are more detailed version of A

A->B-C . You unwindsegue to unwind the stack/pop the view controllers pushed on the stack.

Read this link very useful - http://chrisrisner.com/Unwinding-with-iOS-and-Storyboards

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and has an accepted answer but it did not solve my problem. Therefore, I would like to propose another solution for those who need different approaches.

The story is A presents B, B presents C, A is shown when C is dismissed.
Here is my approach;
Present ViewB from ViewA, when it comes to presenting ViewC from ViewB, do it from ViewA, and dismiss ViewB as follows;

```
let presentingNavCon = navigationController?.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController
let viewC = ViewC()
navigationController?.dismiss(animated: false)
presentingNavCon?.present(viewC, animated: true)
```

so, when you dismiss ViewC, ViewA appears.