# How to remove a UIViewController after having performed a segue?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, segue

As an exercise I would like to not use a navigation controller.

I have the following project:

[image: storyboard screenshot with segues]

The 2 push segues are triggered by each button in the center of the ViewControllers. They use the following custom class:

```swift
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    
    override func perform() {
        
        weak var firstView = self.source.view as UIView?
        weak var secondView = self.destination.view as UIView?
        
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        
        secondView?.frame = CGRect(x: screenSize.width, y: 0.0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
        
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(secondView!, aboveSubview: firstView!)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            
            firstView!.frame = firstView!.frame.offsetBy(dx: -1 * screenSize.width, dy: 0.0)
            secondView!.frame = secondView!.frame.offsetBy(dx: -1 * screenSize.width, dy: 0.0)
            
        }) { (_) -> Void in
            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

This goes extremely wrong because it creates a new ViewController object at each segue performed. The memory usage keeps going up and never down as `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.subviews` is getting filled with UIViews...

The project I am working on has several ViewControllers which can call any other randomly. For this reason I didn't succeed to use `UIViewController.dismiss(animated:completion:)` because it systematically makes it go back to the previous ViewController.

How can I definitely remove the previous ViewController after having performed a segue?

Comment: [Possibly unwind segues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661777/dismiss-presenting-view-controller)

Comment: @shim Yes it would work for 2 view controllers, but as I said my project has several of them and they can called any others in any order, which prevent using unwind

Comment: Why don't you want to use a navigation controller?

Comment: This is a requirement from my customer, I didn't create the project I am making modifications only...

Comment: Also `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification` is for the application going to the background (as in closed by the user), not a view controller.

Comment: Instead of presenting subsequent view controllers on top of the previous one why don't you dismiss them first and then present the new one on some base view controller?

Comment: True this try was way out of track, I will edit my question as it adds nothing

Comment: I didn't think of this, I will try to see if the transitions don't get too heavy. But it would be better being able to dismissed view controllers which are in background...

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel; this is what `UINavigationController` is for.

Comment: @Cinn - do you NOT want a navigation stack? That is, you want any view controller to navigate to any other view controller, but you don't want the ability to go Back to the previous one(s)?

Comment: @DonMag The problem is that the user may or may not go back to the previous view controller, its navigation is random

Comment: @Cinn - ok... so, it's more of a logic question, or maybe a definition question. Suppose you have 4 VCs; user goes `A - B - C - D - B`. Is the user going ***back*** to `B` from `D`? Or ***forward***? What about `A - B - C - D - B - D`? Forward to `D` / forward to `B` / then what... ***back*** or ***forward*** to `D`? Are your VCs setup so that forward or backward even matters?

Comment: You can use a `UINavigationController` and use `setViewControllers` to control which screen the user is brought to next. There are some delegate methods you could take advantage of as well.

Comment: @DonMag Forward and backward doesn't matter, so the user is going forward to D, then forward to B, then to D. The order really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, you don't want traditional "Navigation Controller" features - mainly, you don't need a "Back" button.

So, one option would be to use Child View Controllers.

Your "main" view controller would have nothing but a "container" view. On startup, you load your first VC as a Child VC, and add its view as a subview of the container. When you want to "navigate" to any other VC, load that VC as a Child VC, replace the current view in the container with the new ChildVC's view, and unload the current Child VC.

Comment: I tried your solution following [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) and it works great! This is super clean and fast.